# reverse map-projection: how to get lat/lon coordinates from projected coordinates

Tags: r, geo, map-projections

I have a set of lat/lon coords which I can project using, for example, Mollweide projection.

```
library(mapproj)
set.seed(0)
n <- 100
s <- data.frame(lon = rnorm(n, 0, 60),
                lat = rnorm(n, 0, 40))
p <- mapproject(s$lon, s$lat, proj="mollweide", par=NULL, 
                orientation=c(90,200,0))                 

# plot projected coors
plot(p$x, p$y, type="n", asp=1/1, bty="n")
map.grid(c(-180, 180, -90, 90), nx=20, ny=20, 
         font=1, col=grey(.6), labels=F)
points(p$x, p$y, pch="x", cex = .8)

# a point to reverse project
points(1,0, pch=16, col="red", cex=2)
```

[image]

Now, I have a scenario where I need to do some calculations on the projected coordinates and reverse project the results back to lat/lon coords. For example, how can I reverse project the red point `[1,0]`?

**Any ideas how that can be done?**

Comment: Is there some reason you need to use `mapproject` to project in the fist place.  If you can use `spTransform` instead, then this becomes easier because you can also use spTransform to reverse the same process.

Comment: @dww There is no reason, I just do not know how to do the above using `sp`. So an `sp` solution is also welcome, if understandable for `sp` newbees :)

Comment: Ok, I added an answer already showing how to do it for mapproject.  I can add also another answer for how to do the whole thing in `spTransform` without mapproject - if you also require this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if there's a reason you need to use `mapproject` to project in the fist place. If you can use `spTransform` instead, then this becomes easier because you can also use `spTransform` to reverse the same process.

Assuming that you do need to use `mapproject`, we can still use `spTransform` to convert points from your projected coordinate system into lat-long coordinates, but a little more fiddling is required to deal with the non-standard format of the `mapproject` projections I.e. the points are normalised to lie between -1 to 1 latitude and -2 to 2 longitude. In more standard map projections the lat/long are expressed in distances (usually meters).

So, first we can use spTransform to find out the conversion factors we need to convert the normalised mapproject coordinates into actual distances:

```
library(rgdal)
my.points = data.frame(x=c(0,180),y=c(90,0))
my.points = SpatialPoints(my.points, CRS('+proj=longlat'))
my.points = spTransform(my.points, CRS('+proj=moll'))
# SpatialPoints:
#             x       y
# [1,]        0 9020048
# [2,] 18040096       0
# Coordinate Reference System (CRS) arguments: +proj=moll +ellps=WGS84
```

Now we can use these references to convert from normalised mapproject coordinates into distances in meters:

```
my.points = data.frame(x=p$x * 18040096/2 , y=p$y * 9020048)
my.points = SpatialPoints(my.points, CRS('+proj=moll'))
```

And reproject these into lat/long geographic coordinates:

```
my.points = as.data.frame(spTransform(my.points, CRS('+proj=longlat')))
```

Finally we need to rotate these points by longitude, to undo the rotation that was performed in `mapproject`.

```
my.points$x = my.points$x + 200
my.points$x[my.points$x > 180] = my.points$x[my.points$x > 180] - 360
```

And lets check that it worked:

```
head(my.points)
#           x          y
# 1  75.77725  31.274368
# 2 -19.57400 -31.071065
# 3  79.78795 -24.639597
# 4  76.34576   1.863212
# 5  24.87848 -45.215432
# 6 -92.39700  23.068752

head(s)
#         lon        lat
# 1  75.77726  31.274367
# 2 -19.57400 -31.071065
# 3  79.78796 -24.639596
# 4  76.34576   1.863212
# 5  24.87849 -45.215431
# 6 -92.39700  23.068751
```

Comment: you're a star. I figure that in the long run its worthwhile to get used to sp but the learning curve appeared too steep for just a few tasks... Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: I just realised an error that i've now corrected.  I do a lot of climate science, where we ususally use longitudes from zero to 360.  Of course, normally people use -180 to +180. So I've chnaged the rotation to use `my.points$x[my.points$x > 180] = my.points$x[my.points$x > 180] - 360` to work with standard longitudes

Answer (score 2):

If nothing out of the box is available, you could write a function of your own, along the lines of:

```
ref_project <- function(x, y) {
    long <- tibble(
        long = seq(-180, 180, 1),
        x = mapproject(long, rep(0, length(long)), projection = 'mollweide', orientation = c(90, 200, 0))$x
    )
    lat <- tibble(
        lat = seq(-90, 90, 1),
        x = mapproject(rep(0, length(lat)), lat, projection = 'mollweide', orientation = c(90, 200, 0))$y
    )

    return(c(long[which(abs(long$x - x) == min(abs(long$x - x))), 'long'],
             lat[which(abs(lat$x - y) == min(abs(lat$x - y))), 'lat']))
}
```

Comment: Basically, you suggest a lookup table for the projected coordinates. While a simple idea, it is very approximate, leading to slightly imprecise back-conversions. Of course, one could have a finder grained sequence. Maybe this will work. Props for this simple hands-on idea :)